# Does PostgreSQL OIDs change over time?

Tags: postgresql

**Context**

I'm creating a service where users can manage it's own database tables.

I found two ways of reference a table:

1. Name: `table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables`
2. OID: `relid from pg_class`

The same for columns:

1. Name: `table_schema, table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns`
2. attnum: `attrelid, attnum from pg_attribute`

I don't want use the name directly, because it can change over time (can be renamed)

**Question**

Is it safe to use these numbers as references?

I found little to no useful information in [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html)

Comment: The useful information is right at the beginning "Object identifiers (OIDs) are used internally by PostgreSQL as primary keys for various system tables. "  Start `psql` with -E and you will get the internal queries Postgres uses. You will see `OID`s are used extensively. So yes they are safe to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use the `oid` as permanent reference to a table.

While the `oid` never changes during the life time of a database, it will be different after a restore from a `pg_dump`.

Also a major upgrade, be it with dump/restore or `pg_upgrade`, will change the `oid`s.

Answer (score 0):

No, OIDs do not change.  They will be different if an object is dropped and recreated as that will count as a new object, but otherwise they will stay as they are.  The same applies to columns (attributes), where the attnum will remain the same unless the column is dropped and recreated.  attnum values are never reused for the same table.

Comment: A dump and restore of the database can (and probably will) change the oids